# Keep getting nil error everywhere. ruby/rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3

I get a NoMethodError: undefined method `get_best_compatible' for nil:NilClass in mail

```
`from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in 'method_missing'from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.2.7/lib/mail/body.rb:143:in 'get_best_encoding' from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mail2.2.7/lib/mail/message.rb:1830:in 'identify_and_set_transfer_encoding' from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.2.7/lib/mail/message.rb:1646:in 'ready_to_send!' from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mail 2.2.7/lib/mail/message.rb:1664:in 'encoded' from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.2.7/lib/mail/message.rb:1672:in 'to_s'`
```

*when using the mail gem*

---

I get a `You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.split` error when using the oauth gem

---

*and even when I am running **rails g** in my project I am getting* `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/generators.rb:232:in 'help': You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! (NoMethodError)
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.map!`

Note that these stuff worked perfectly a few days ago and I have no idea how I managed to mess up this bad my project.
Using *ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [x86_64-linux]*

Answer (score 1):

Phew just found out why. I have ovverriden the Sting.downcase with String.mb_char.downcase and I thought it was fine. Thanks ruby-debugger :-)